# WPF Toggle Switch's and Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 2 ToggleSwitch's and I only want one of them to be enabled at a time. So if one is on the other is off and visa versa. I though I could achieve this using triggers but I am having a bit of trouble.

The logic seems to be working as desired, however only the first switch you change checked state will work e.g. If I first toggle swich1, switch2 will toggle the opposite state. However if I toggle switch2, it will not toggle switch1. If I start the application and toggle switch2 first, switch1 will toggle as expected.

Heres the xaml:

```
    <controls:ToggleSwitch Name="Toggle1">
                    <controls:ToggleSwitch.Style>                           
                        <Style TargetType="controls:ToggleSwitch">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value >
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.7" ScaleY="0.7" CenterY="5" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>

                            <!-- Here is the 'normal' default content -->
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentGroup.IsDistributionGroup}"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <!-- Here is how we bind to another control's property -->
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Toggle2}" Value="True">
                                    <!-- Here is the 'override' content -->
                                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Toggle2}" Value="False">
                                     <!--Here is the 'override' content--> 
                                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </controls:ToggleSwitch.Style>
                </controls:ToggleSwitch>


    <controls:ToggleSwitch Name="Toggle2">
                    <controls:ToggleSwitch.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="controls:ToggleSwitch">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value >
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.7" ScaleY="0.7" CenterY="5" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>

                            <!-- Here is the 'normal' default content -->
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentGroup.IsGroupAgents}"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <!-- Here is how we bind to another control's property -->
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Toggle1}" Value="True">
                                    <!-- Here is the 'override' content -->
                                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Toggle1}" Value="False">
                                    <!-- Here is the 'override' content -->
                                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </controls:ToggleSwitch.Style>
                </controls:ToggleSwitch>
```

Comment: How about just re-templating togglebutton and hiding the logic behind if it is DistributionGroup or GroupAgents in the viewmodel behind a boolean field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from code-behind, and works with ToggleButton.  I am unfamiliar with ToggleSwitch.

```
        Toggle1.Checked += Toggle1_Checked;
        Toggle1.Unchecked += Toggle1_Unchecked;
        Toggle2.Checked += Toggle2_Checked;
        Toggle2.Unchecked += Toggle2_Unchecked;
    }

    private void Toggle2_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Toggle1.IsChecked = true;
    }

    private void Toggle2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Toggle1.IsChecked = false;
    }

    private void Toggle1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Toggle2.IsChecked = true;
    }

    private void Toggle1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Toggle2.IsChecked = false;
    }
```

Also, in your code above, it is unclear where the initial Checked values for each toggle are.  Do you set one to checked and the other to unchecked initially somewhere?  Unsure if that will solve your problem either.

Also, you get this same behavior from `RadioButton` which can be re-styled, and supports grouping via `GroupName` so each radio button is mutually exclusive.  It derives from ToggleButton.